# Java, JMS shutdown connection when receive all response.

Tags: java, jms, response

I have problem with counting responses from response queue. I mean, once per day we run a job which gather some data from db and send them to queue. When we receive all responses we should shutdown connection. The problem is how we can check if all responses arrived ? Keeping this in global variable is risky because of concurrence issue. Any idea ? I am quite new in JMS so maybe solution is obvious but I dont see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your stack is or whatever tools you might be using to accomplish this but I've got this in mind and this might help you out (hopefully).

1. Generate a hash for each job you plan on queuing and store it in a concurrent list/map. (i.e: `ConcurrentHashMap`)
2. Send the job to the queue.
3. Once the job is done and sends back a response, reproduce the hash and store it a separate concurrent list/map that holds all the jobs that are done.

Now that you have two lists of all the jobs supposed to be executed and the jobs that you got a response from. There multiple ways to accomplish this. If you lookup `Java Concurrency`, you'd find plenty of tutorials and documentation. I like to use CyclicBarrier`and`CountDownLatch`. If plan on using any of these methods, take extra precautions to prevent your application from hanging or worse, a filthy memory leak.

OR, you could simply check on how many queuing requests and responses you've and if they are equal to each other, drop the connection.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply, I am using spring boot with JMS (IBM MQ implementation)